# Change the array size of a structure's member for an array in VB.NET at one time

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure

Here is my structure:

```
Public Structure Plant
    Public Position() As Double
    Dim Cost As Double
    Dim Seed As Double
End Structure
```

I need to change the `Position` array's size after connecting it to an array.

```
Dim Population(10) As Plant
```

If I want to change the `Position` array's size, I should define each for each number of Population.

For example:

```
    ReDim Population(0).Position(9)
    ReDim Population(1).Position(9)
```

But regarding the fact that in our program all members of `Population` variable have the same `Position` size (9), is there any simplest way to allocate the size at the one to all members of Population and position variables? instead of using a loop such as

```
for i=0 to 10
        ReDim Population(i).Position(9)
next i
```

I changed the structure definition to

```
   Public Structure Plant
        Public Position() As Double
        Dim Cost As Double
        Dim Seed As Double

        Private Sub New(ByVal VariableSize As Integer)
            ReDim Position(VariableSize)
        End Sub
    End Structure
```

And defined this variable:

```
 Dim Population(Npop0) As Plant = New Plant(9)
```

But I got this error

> Explicit initialization is not permitted for arrays declared with explicit bounds

Comment: Array is rarely the correct collection type to select these days, unless you are *actually implementing a collection type yourself*. There are plenty of collection types to choose from and only one, the array, is so odd as to have a fixed length but mutable contents.

Comment: Thank you, I need to code an old VBA program that doesn't support different libraries, I need to test my code first in VB.NET and I need to use array.

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions there. You need to post them separately in that case. That error message is unrelated to how to resize the arrays so, if you want to know how to fix that, post a separate question.

Comment: I think the compiler may be getting confused as your declaration could be for an array with a particular bound or it could be calling the constructor.  What happens if you use an explicit parameter name for it i.e. `... = New Plant(VariableSize:=9)`?

Comment: I would also recommend to consider changing to `Class` in .NET.  There are important behavioral differences between `Class` and `Structure`.  As a general rule, everything in a `Structure` should be immutable (read-only and fixed at the time of construction) else you can get hard-to-reason-about behavior due to the rules on making temporary copies when `Structure`s are changed.